# Vue: Get HTML Attributes from vNode

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

```
const Heading = {
   name: "Heading",
   setup() {
      // vue-jsx
      return () => <div id="example-id" style={{ color: 'red' }}></div>
   }
}
```

```
const vNode = createVNode(Heading)
```

**Now how can I get `id` or `style` attribute from the child markup inside `vNode`?**

Note: `vNode.props.style` return undefined

Comment: If you didn't explicitly define them as props, they are attributes and available through useAttrs